# Node.js loop on API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, csv, object

I am trying to get few API calls with different parameters. Get the data and convert it into CSV file by day, city highest temp, city lowest temp and cities with rain.

API example:
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

I have the following Object with cities and api key:

```
const cities = {
    0: ['Jerusalem', 'il'],
    1: ['New York', 'us'],
    2: ['Dubai', 'ae'],
    3: ['Lisbon', 'pt'],
    4: ['Oslo', 'no'],
    5: ['Paris', 'fr'],
    6: ['Berlin', 'de'],
    7: ['Athens', 'gr'],
    8: ['Seoul', 'kr'],
    9: ['Singapore', 'sgp'],
}

const apiKey = "[retracted]";
```

This is my API call which I want to iterate dynamically, currently I run it only on the first object params and eventually push the info to weather so I can manipulate the data to order it by days(5 first days), then display the city with the highest temp, city with the lowests temp and all the cities with rain:

```
request(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${cities[1][0]},${cities[1][1]}&mode=json&appid=${apiKey}`, (error, response, body) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(body);    
    let weather = {
        0: [day, highTemp, lowTemp, rain],
        1: [day, highTemp, lowTemp, rain],
        2: [day, highTemp, lowTemp, rain],
        3: [day, highTemp, lowTemp, rain],
        4: [day, highTemp, lowTemp, rain],
    }
    // day 1
    console.log(data['city']['name']);
    console.log(data['list'][0].dt_txt);
    console.log(data['list'][0].main['temp']);

    // day 2
    console.log(data['city']['name']);
    console.log(data['list'][8].dt_txt);
    console.log(data['list'][8].main['temp']);
    // day 3
    console.log(data['city']['name']);
    console.log(data['list'][16].dt_txt);
    console.log(data['list'][16].main['temp']);
    // day 4
    console.log(data['city']['name']);
    console.log(data['list'][24].dt_txt);
    console.log(data['list'][24].main['temp']);
    // day 5
    console.log(data['city']['name']);
    console.log(data['list'][32].dt_txt);
    console.log(data['list'][32].main['temp']);

});
```

I've tried to use for loop with key in object but unfortunately it doesn't display the data, cause of error undefined.

Comment: are you getting your data in response or in body?

Comment: in body, then I parse it and save it to data.
The console.logs works perfectly, I just want to make the loop over the API with the different params I get from object cities. I assume we need to use Promise but I am not quite familiar with it which made me lots of troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using response-promise-native to allow the use of async / await. This will allow us to iterate through the city list and attach the weather data for each city to the city details (name and country).

Once we have this data, we can do the processing you've mentioned, we can get max and min temperatures (take note, the temperatures are in Kelvin, so we'll convert to Celsius.)

It's important to point out that I'm grouping by *local date*, if you wish to group by *utc date* then you should change the line:

```
let timeOffset = entry.dt + result.weatherResponse.city.timezone;
```

to

```
let timeOffset = entry.dt;
```

This is a slightly different way of interpreting the data!

I have now updated to group by date the results looks like so:

Grouping by local date:

```
Date,Highest Temperature,Lowest Temperature,Cities With Rain
2019-11-01,Dubai,Oslo,"Paris,Berlin"
2019-11-02,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Singapore"
2019-11-03,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Athens,Singapore"
2019-11-04,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Athens"
2019-11-05,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Singapore"
2019-11-06,Singapore,Oslo,"Paris,Berlin,Singapore"
2019-11-07,Seoul,Seoul,""
```

Grouping by UTC date:

```
Date,Highest Temperature,Lowest Temperature,Cities With Rain
2019-11-01,Dubai,Oslo,"Paris,Berlin"
2019-11-02,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Singapore"
2019-11-03,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Athens,Singapore"
2019-11-04,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Athens"
2019-11-05,Singapore,Oslo,"Lisbon,Paris,Berlin,Singapore"
2019-11-06,Singapore,Oslo,"Paris,Berlin,Singapore"
```

The code:

```
const rp = require("request-promise-native");

const cities = {
    0: ['Jerusalem', 'il'],
    1: ['New York', 'us'],
    2: ['Dubai', 'ae'],
    3: ['Lisbon', 'pt'],
    4: ['Oslo', 'no'],
    5: ['Paris', 'fr'],
    6: ['Berlin', 'de'],
    7: ['Athens', 'gr'],
    8: ['Seoul', 'kr'],
    9: ['Singapore', 'sgp'],
}


async function getWeatherForCities() {
    let results = [];
    for (let [city, countryCode] of Object.values(cities)) {
        console.log(`Getting weather for city: ${city}, country: ${countryCode}...`);
        let weatherResponse = await rp({ url: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},${countryCode}&mode=json&appid=${apiKey}`, json: true});
        results.push ({ city, countryCode, list: weatherResponse.list, weatherResponse });
    }

    let summary = results.map(res => {  
        return { city: res.city, countryCode: res.countryCode,
        maxTemperature: getMaxTemperatureCelsius(res.list),
        minTemperature: getMinTemperatureCelsius(res.list),
        totalRainfall: getTotalRainFall(res.list)
    }});

    console.log("Summary (over forecasting interval): ", summary);
    console.log("Result with the highest temperature: ", [...summary].sort((resA, resB) => resB.maxTemperature - resA.maxTemperature)[0]);
    console.log("Result with the lowest temperature: ", [...summary].sort((resA, resB) => resA.minTemperature - resB.minTemperature)[0]);
    console.log("Cities with rain: ", summary.filter(res => res.totalRainfall).map(res => res.city));

    // Group by date (local) and city
    let resultsGroupedByDateAndCity = {};
    results.forEach(result => {
        result.list.forEach(entry => {
            let timeOffset = entry.dt + result.weatherResponse.city.timezone;
            let date = new Date(timeOffset * 1000);
            date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            let dateKey = date.toISOString().substring(0,10);
            if (!resultsGroupedByDateAndCity[dateKey]) resultsGroupedByDateAndCity[dateKey] = {};
            if (!resultsGroupedByDateAndCity[dateKey][result.city]) resultsGroupedByDateAndCity[dateKey][result.city] = [];
            resultsGroupedByDateAndCity[dateKey][result.city].push(entry);
        });
    });

    // Run through the keys.
    let csvLines = ["Date,Highest Temperature,Lowest Temperature,Cities With Rain"];

    for (let [date, obj] of Object.entries(resultsGroupedByDateAndCity)) {
        let dailySummary = Object.entries(obj).map(([city, dayList]) => {  
            return { city,
            maxTemperature: getMaxTemperatureCelsius(dayList),
            minTemperature: getMinTemperatureCelsius(dayList),
            totalRainfall: getTotalRainFall(dayList)
        }});

        console.log("Details for date " + date + ": ");
        let resultWithHighestTemperature = [...dailySummary].sort((resA, resB) => resB.maxTemperature - resA.maxTemperature)[0];
        let resultWithLowestTemperature = [...dailySummary].sort((resA, resB) => resA.minTemperature - resB.minTemperature)[0];
        let citiesWithRain = dailySummary.filter(res => res.totalRainfall).map(res => res.city);
        console.log("Result with the highest temperature: ", resultWithHighestTemperature);
        console.log("Result with the lowest temperature: ", resultWithLowestTemperature);
        console.log("Cities with rain: ", citiesWithRain);

        csvLines.push([date, resultWithHighestTemperature.city, resultWithLowestTemperature.city, '"' + citiesWithRain.join(",") + '"'].join(","));
    }

    console.log("CSV result:\n", csvLines.join("\n"));
}

function KelvinToCelsius(kelvin) {
    return (kelvin - 273.15);
}

// Return the max temperature for the forecast
function getMaxTemperatureCelsius(responseList) {
    // Get a list of the max temperatures for the forecast.
    const maxTemps = responseList.map(entry => Number(entry.main.temp_max));
    return KelvinToCelsius(Math.max(...maxTemps));
}

// Return the min temperature for the forecast
function getMinTemperatureCelsius(responseList) {
    // Get a list of the min temperatures for the forecast.
    const minTemps = responseList.map(entry => Number(entry.main.temp_min));
    return KelvinToCelsius(Math.min(...minTemps));
}

// Return the total rainfall for the forecast
function getTotalRainFall(responseList) {
    // Get a list of the min temperatures for the forecast.
    const rain = responseList.map(entry => { return entry.rain ? Number(entry.rain["3h"]): 0 });
    return rain.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0)
}

getWeatherForCities();
```

Comment: This answer gave me the best solution so far, how can I manipulate it btw.

Comment: I've added functions to get the max. and min. temperature for each city, I'll add some functionality to order cities by max temperature, min. temperature. etc!

Comment: There is one problem though, look at the following API
[link](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)
It returns weather by days. I need the five days. 
I managed to display it by adding +8 inside the loop which is inside the API call.

Comment: For example:
`
 let data = JSON.parse(body);
//             for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
//           let day = 0;
          
//         cityName = data["city"]["name"];
//         cityDate = data["list"][day].dt_txt;
//         cityTemp = data["list"][day].main["temp"];
//         cityRain = data["list"][day].weather[0].main;
//         let weather = 
//         obj.push({
//             city : cityName,
//             date : cityDate,
//             temperature : cityTemp,
//             rain : cityRain
//         });
//         day + 8;
//       }
`

Comment: much appreciated, very helpful!

Comment: Each response will give us 40 data points, up to 8 for each day. This usually means we'll get data covering 6 days (2 partial + 4 complete), e.g 5,8,8,8,8,3. I think the most robust way to assign weather to a day is to use the dt unix timestamp and use moment.js perhaps to get the day from it (moment.utc(dt)) (I presume they're using UTC time!) If we just skip each 8 data points we'll risk assigning the wrong day to the weather.

Comment: The API give up to 5 days, which in my opinion won't risk the days. 
They explain it here in the API documentation: 
https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

They display weather forecast every three hours for 5 days. 
Which mean +8 is the exact hour for every city. That's how I received the updated forecast.
Maybe I am wrong, do you have a solution for the 8+ method so I can check it out? 
Cause still the for(let key in object) display only the first days of each city but not all the 5 days.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're doing, you're taking a snapshot 1 day apart for 5 days. That will work! My logic was to get the maximum value (for each parameter) from the 40 readings for each location.

Comment: I get your point, it is a good logic but I try the simpler way. 
Let me know if you changed it on the posted answer, for the meanwhile I will try to figure how to display the five different days and compare between each single day. 
So like that I will be able to display the final results into CSV file.

Comment: Will do!, I've added a list of cities with rainfall (simple map and filter to do this), we get the total rainfall for the city (in mm) then filter any with 0mm rain.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand though, sorry for my lack of experience.
When you map the list and use the entry of main.temp_max. How do you know which of the lists it is using? because inside list there are 40 objects.

Comment: Oh sure, yes. I'm passing the weatherResponse for each location to getMaxTemperatureCelsius for example. Once in this function I call list.map(entry => Number(entry.main.temp_max)). This runs through the 40 entries for Berlin, for example and we assign the 40 max temperatures to the maxTemps array. At this point we just do a Math.max to get the maximum of this list. You could also use array.reduce for this purpose, that would give you the result in one line.

Comment: I see. But since we are comparing between the five different days that method not relevant anymore, correct? since the temp_max will include all the five days. 
I find it very difficult to separate the five days and each day with its own highest/lowest temp. How can I separate them for each day?

Comment: The point is that I need eventually to use the cities list, and get the weather forecast for each city of the next 5 days using the api then save the forecast in to a CSV file as follows:
Day, city with highest temp, city with lowest temp, cities with rain

Comment: Sorry to disturb you so much, did you manage to do it? 
For some reason I don't find a solution. I think I am doing something wrong

Comment: I'm looking at it.. it is tricky enough.... :-).. We need to group reading by day, then get the max, min, rainy days etc.. I'll get there!!

Comment: I've updated to summarize the weather by day and by city then create a CSV report based on this... as I said tricky enough :-).. You could also group by UTC day if you wish, though I don't think this is really correct.

Comment: You are a life saver, could take me a week to finish this. 
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: No problem,  glad to be of help!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to achieve this.

> Promise.all returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the
>   promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable
>   contains no promises.

```
const getData = (url) => {
   return fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(jsonData => jsonData)
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error while resolving the promise for url", url);        
    });  
}

let arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const cities = {
    0: ['Jerusalem', 'il'],
    1: ['New York', 'us'],
    2: ['Dubai', 'ae'],
    3: ['Lisbon', 'pt'],
    4: ['Oslo', 'no'],
    5: ['Paris', 'fr'],
    6: ['Berlin', 'de'],
    7: ['Athens', 'gr'],
    8: ['Seoul', 'kr'],
    9: ['Singapore', 'sgp'],
}

const apiKey = "[retracted]";

Promise.all(Object.keys(cities).map(id => {  
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${cities[id][0]},${cities[id][1]}&mode=json&appid=${apiKey}`;
  return getData(url);
  }))
 .then(results => {

        // results is an array that contains the result of each api call
        // so you can perform the action that you need here..

        results.map(result => {

          console.log(result['city']['name']);

        });

  })
  .catch(err => {
        // Handle the error..
        console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of fetch(URL) in get data if I call the API in Promise.all?

Comment: @YonatanDarmon I overlooked that point, thanks. Edited the redundant promise call in `getData`.

Comment: You're looping through the `cities` and `fetch`ing the data one by one and then `Promise.all` returns all the data as a single promise.

Comment: But the fetch URL is not dynamic which get me only one response. 
I need to do it dynamically so if I change cities in the array it will be able to proceed with the new changes. 

I added an API example on top of my question